# How to analyze netstat for suspicious connections?

Tags: passwords

Somebody accessed my Microsoft account this morning and the IP that did it came from Thailand. A couple of days prior the incident, I noticed that my Command Prompt opened and closed immediately many times through out the day. I feel certain when I say that I'm being hacked. Would somebody please help me analyze my netstat results? Thank you very much
[image]

Comment: To what end...?

Comment: I'm not sure what we can do with that snippet

Comment: There are ways for malware to hide from netstat and other such tools. When you suspect your system is compromised, you should follow the standard procedure: Wipe the hard drive and restore from backup.

Comment: "*Somebody accessed my Microsoft account*" - what Microsoft account?